# Always display decimal places

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a very basic C# function that does a multiplication calculation on decimals. I then display the results in the console. I also limit the amount of decimal places to be displayed to two. A very basic form of this is shown below:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
result = a*b;

Console.Write("Result = " + result.ToString("0.##"));
```

Now what I want to do is display the two decimal places all the time. So in this case I want it to display **Result = 50.00** and not just Result = 50.

Comment: Console.Write(5.ToString("f2"));

Comment: From [The `"#"` Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD) **Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed.** That's why you can use [The `"0"` Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Specifier0) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`#` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD) will omit's trailing `0`'s. Given you want to retain these I suggest you use either the [0 specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Specifier0)

```
result.ToString("0.00");
```

Or the [Fixed-point specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FFormatString)

```
result.ToString("F2");
```

See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F2}",result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("F2"));
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Standard Numeric Format Strings)